# How do I solve linker errors from the Cocoapods lint command?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have a library written for iOS in Objective-C that we publish via Cocoapods, and recently I've been getting a pair of link errors when I try to validate the pod with the `pod lib lint` command. Both errors look like this (with names changed to protect the innocent):

```
Ld /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akupndrkecikjfdfvjfyniytivhf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Binary/App normal x86_64 (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    cd /var/folders/4v/jcw9j9x126j5wsmpqmhhswx40000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20191211-37020-sasgf-FooBarSDK
    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk -L/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akupndrkecikjfdfvjfyniytivhf/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -L/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akupndrkecikjfdfvjfyniytivhf/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/FooBarSDK -L/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akupndrkecikjfdfvjfyniytivhf/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/TFooBarSDK -L/var/folders/4v/jcw9j9x126j5wsmpqmhhswx40000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20191211-37020-sasgf-FooBarSDK/Pods/TFooBarSDK/FooBar -F/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akupndrkecikjfdfvjfyniytivhf/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akupndrkecikjfdfvjfyniytivhf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akupndrkecikjfdfvjfyniytivhf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App_lto.o -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lFooBar_1.2.4 -lFooBarSDK -lTFooBarSDK -lz -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akupndrkecikjfdfvjfyniytivhf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/App.app-Simulated.xcent -framework Foundation -lPods-App -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akupndrkecikjfdfvjfyniytivhf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akupndrkecikjfdfvjfyniytivhf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Binary/App
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FooBar", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_FooBar_$_ForceLoad in libFooBarSDK.a(FooBarEmpty.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The problem may have started when I moved the project up to Xcode 10.3 or 11.2 (happens the same with both versions) from Xcode 9.x, or that might be a red herring.

My understanding is that, among other sanity checks, `pod lib lint` creates an application project that includes the library in question (`libFooBarSDK` in this case) and tries to build it, and it looks like that project's linking phase is what generates this error. However, our test application links against the library with no problems.

`pod --version` says I'm using version 1.7.5 of Cocoapods, by the way.

My questions:

- Is this problem related to switching to a newer Xcode version?
- How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the option `--verbose` to get a more detailed log about the failure. Add the option `--no-clean` to save the Xcode workspace from which you can debug the linker symbol problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in Pods, but if this check does create a demo project like you wrote, maybe it has a build phase for removing simulator architecture (in order to avoid AppStore rejection).

This script is usually a variation of this one: http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

If the project build runs such a script, the build might fail when the target is a simulator and not a real device.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I don't think that's it. Cocoapods is a tool for distributing libraries to other developers, and none of those libraries can go to the App Store without first being built into an app. The test project that I mentioned is created on the fly and then deleted.